# serializing float32 values in python and deserializing them in C++

Tags: python, c++, json, serialization, floating-point

I have a bunch of 32-bit floating point values in a Python script, need to store them to disc and load them in a C++ tool.
Currently they are written in human-readable format. However the loss of precision is too big for my (numeric) application.

How do I best store (and load) them without loss?

Comment: json only has one way to represent numbers, so that pretty much limits your options, no?  http://www.json.org/  I would recommend using a serialization library, however.   Don't try to figure this stuff out yourself -- it can get complicated.

Comment: @xaxxon Thanks for the remark. I can use base64 to store any binary format in json. I edit my question accordingly.

Comment: The JSON part is completely meaningless to your question at that point, since you can literally store anything as a base-64 encoded string.   I suggest just removing that part entirely as it doesn't add anything except potential confusion.

Comment: @xaxxon You are right. Thanks. I removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `float.hex` in python to get the hexadecimal representation of your number, then read it using the `std::hexfloat` stream manipulator in C++.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Do you know if this is portable between different systems? The [documentation for std::hexfloat](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) does not mention IEEE etc.

Comment: According to the c++14 standard, `std::hexfloat` is equivalent to a call of `str.setf(ios_base::fixed | ios_base::scientific, ios_base::floatfield)`, and `ios_base::fixed | ios_base::scientific` is a format equivalent to stdio's `%A`. According to the C11 standard, the result is correctly rounded if `FLT_RADIX` is a power of 2.

Comment: Also, the Python documentation states that `float.hex` and `float.fromhex` are compatible with stdio's `%a`/`%A`.

Comment: Well, this is better than decimal representation because avoids expensive conversion.

Answer (score 2):

> Currently they are written in the default human-readable format.

That's the reason. If require e.g. "%.9e" or "%.9g", it will print float32 values with precision enough to restore (provided there is no errors in conversions).

Also, for Python3, `repr()` gives a shortest decimal representation for a value that is converted back to the same binary value; but this is not true for Python2.

Answering a question from comments,

> If I understand correctly, there are values that have a finite floating point representation in base 2, but the base 10 representation is infinite,

No, it is finite anyway, but just longer. For example (Python3)

```
>>> math.pi
3.141592653589793
>>> '%.60g' % math.pi
'3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875'
```

but, all digits after the final significant one do not matter (remember Python `float` is double precision):

```
>>> float('3.1415926535897931')
3.141592653589793
>>> float('3.1415926535897932')
3.141592653589793
>>> float('3.1415926535897933')
3.141592653589793
>>> float('3.1415926535897933') - float('3.1415926535897931')
0.0
```

Finally, hexadecimal is more reliable if available in your code. I expect your Python and C++ versions fresh enough to support %a (stdio), float.hex (Python).

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to store them without any loss. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Yep. For float32, 8 significant decimal digits are enough for no loss.

Comment: If I understand correctly, there are values that have a finite floating point representation in base 2, but the base 10 representation is infinite, i.e. one would need an infinite number of digits after the decimal separator to represent them. Short: No, there should always be a loss in precision when using your approach.

Comment: 1. No, there is no infinite decimal representation of binary number. Just additional digits in full representation. 2. These additional digits won't change what binary float32 number is closest to them.

Comment: @Netch: you need 9 significant digits, not 8. For example, `0x1.fffffep+9 = 1023.99993896484375` and `0x1.fffffcp+9 = 1023.9998779296875` are distinct exactly-representable `float32` values, but their decimal representations agree when rounded to 8 significant digits: both give `1023.9999`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson thanks, that's too subtle and I've missed it. Hope to remember for future :)

Comment: @Netch Ah OK, thanks. I think I now understand. 2 is a prime factor of 10 (base in decimal), so one can express every binary float in decimal. Is it just the other way that can make problems, since for example 1/5 can be expressed cleanly in decimal but not in binary since 5 is a prime factor of 10 but not of 2.